# R interactive usa map

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, choropleth

I am trying to create a choropleth map in R, I've tried a few different ways with no success. I am looking for a basic U.S map that on hover shows the state name and the median salary with a legend that shows darker coloring for higher salary.

Here is what my data frame looks like:

```
> stateDF
# A tibble: 51 x 2
   State  Median
   <fct>   <dbl>
  1 AL     91400.
  2 AK    130000.
  3 AZ    110000.
  4 AK     92000.
  5 CA    125000.
  6 CO    101000.
  7 CT    115000.
  8 DE    105300.
  9 DL    102000.
 10 GA    104000.
  # ... with 41 more rows


> dput(head(stateDF))
structure(list(State = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("AL", 
"AK", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "DL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", 
"IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MS", "MO", 
"MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", 
"OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VI", "WA", 
"WV", "WI", "WY", "DC"), class = "factor"), Median = c(91400, 
130000, 110000, 92000, 125000, 101000)), .Names = c("State", 
"Median"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Here's what I've tried (neither work):

```
  ##this displays the map correctly but I can't figure out how to get the hover text to display my Median for each state

states <- map_data("state")
p <- ggplot(data = states) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = region, group = group), color = 
  "white") + 
  coord_fixed(1.3) +
  guides(fill=FALSE)+
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) + 
  theme(axis.line = element_blank()) + 
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank()) 


 ##This does not display a map, but the legend looks like it's reading the medians correctly

 plot_ly(type="choropleth", 
        locations=stateDF$State, 
        locationmode="USA-states",
        z=stateDF$Median) %>% 
  layout(.,geo=list(scope="usa"),)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Look at the libraries `googleway`, `leaflet` and `mapview` for interactive maps

Comment: Use leaflet: https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/choropleths.html

Comment: @YifuYan I tried using that, however I get the error  > states <- geojsonio::geojson_read("json/us-states.geojson", what = "sp")
Error: File does not exist. Create it, or fix the path.

Comment: You need to download that geojson data first: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PublicaMundi/MappingAPI/master/data/geojson/us-states.json